# How to replace Unreal Engine Sprites in flipbook?

Tags: unreal-engine4

So I've been making a Paper 2D program with Unreal Engine, I've done all the blueprints needed to make it show the flipbook when walking, and I used that generic blue character.

I want to replace this character sprite with my own pngs, so that I do not have to rewrite all the blueprints from scratch again.

New character

[image]

Old character

[image]

Comment: https://snag.gy/U4B9Zm.jpg (Blueprints for flipbooks)

Comment: NEVER MIND GENTS, I did it myself